# How can I effectively model a property in a relational database?

Tags: database-design

I have seen two approaches to modeling properties in relational databases:

1. Create arbitrary tables that assume all the necessary components of the property. For example, have tables for room, unit, floor, building.
2. Have a single table 'asset'. Use a linking table to create relations between assets.

In either case, the building is represented as a general tree structure. This seems painful to query.

I need to represent this tree in order to implement an RBAC system. Now I'm not so sure that a relational DB is the best solution.

Comment: By "Property" you mean an actual parcel, building, or unit thereof?

Comment: yes exactly. Any property asset from a skyscraper to apartment complex to house.

Comment: It strongly depends on your use cases. What do you need these `assets`/components for? Do they have their own attributes? How are you going to fill that with data? What kind of relations you need here? What kind of queries you expect to be run there? Etc., etc. It may be easier to answer if you would provide more details. With which sql dialect you would be implementing that? You're not sure whether RDB is best solution - what alternative solutions you're thinking of?

Comment: You might in a model in this site: http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/

Comment: All I want is a general tree structure that I can query. I will associate nodes (records) in this tree structure with records in other tables via a foreign key. It is a query on the database to get the node and then a search down all children of that node. I'm trying to keep it simple as possible, suppose its just the tree. I'm not a DB admin but developer so I haven't gone into SQL dialects. I just know that this is a graph structure and it might be better represented by a graph DB or document store where a tree structure is more natural.

Comment: **RDBMS** are great at storing Tree structured data. I'm not sure why you'd think a **document store** would be made for that, **document stores** are more-so for non-relational data and a Tree is relational. Heck, indexed data in a **RDBMS** is logically stored in a Tree-like structure itself (but this is only tangentially related).

Comment: Documents or data storage formats are often trees (xml, html, json). They don't require a search of the DB to pull children. IMO many document stores are made for tree-structured data. The storage of a tree in a B-Tree means you still have to search the B-Tree to build the tree, whereas you can pull a document directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your question is about how to store tree data in an RDBMS. I can't speak to using a graph DB, but can for a RDBMS.

**Overview**

Two common approaches for storing tree data in an RDBMS are:

- Adjacency list (I think this is what you are describing above)
- Nested set

Here is a good overview of how to implement each. http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

And a comparison of performance (in SQL Server, but the basic conclusions should be similar across most databases that allow recursive queries): https://explainextended.com/2009/09/25/adjacency-list-vs-nested-sets-sql-server/

In general, if your tree data isn't going to change and all you need to is to grab all descendants, a nested set is a great solution. If you are frequently updating the tree (adding/removing nodes) then a nested set is not a great solution.

**A possible solution**

One solution I have implemented in the past is to store distinct trees (it sounds like "Property" would be a distinct tree in your case) as an Adjacency List table in the DB, due to ease of inserts/deletions. Then read a distinct tree into your preferred data structure server-side for operations. I don't know if that works in your case.

So something like

```
[Asset] table
- id (pk)
- Parent_AssetID (fk referencing Asset.id)
- Name
- Type
- PropertyID (fk referencing Property.id)

[Property] table
- id
- Name
```

Then you can use the PropertyID column - foreign key to a Property table - to easily query the Asset table and grab all "assets" for that property for processing server-side.